# Unable to understand Memory allocation of structure

Tags: c, memory-management

Consider following C code -

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
}node;

int main()
{
    node *temp;
    temp->data=100;
    printf("%d",temp->data);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives `Segmentation fault` on line containing `temp->data=100;` because (I think) I haven't allocate memory for it. So, there is nothing such as `temp->data`.
But, when I try with -

```
int main()
{
    node *temp,*n;
    n=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->data=100;
    temp->data=n->data;
    printf("%d",temp->data);
    retrun 0;
}
```

It gives proper output 100.
I haven't allocate memory where `temp` will point. But still I am copying `n->data` to `temp->data`. How ??

Comment: Both programs are incorrect - it just so happens that one *appears* to work while the other doesn't.

Comment: Undefined behaviour. It could also crash like the first (and probably does with some compilers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temp pointer takes some garbage value as its not initialised. By chance temp has a garbage value which may happen to be legal address for your program so it runs. If garbage value has illegal adress it will generate segment fault.

Answer (score 1):

You're lucky.

Local variables are not initialized automatically, so when the program begins, both `temp` and `n` contain whatever values happen to be on the stack.  Next, memory is allocated and `n` is set to point to it.  The value 100 is stored in the `data` member of the structure.

But `temp` is still uninitialized, so the value 100 is copied into an unspecified area of memory.  Depending on where that memory happens to be, the program may segfault, or it may simply corrupt memory that it doesn't own.

Answer (score 1):

That you haven't got a segfault in `temp->data=n->data;` is just coincidence. `temp` is not initialized and hence it points into the digital nirvana.

When you've called `malloc` you've allocated `sizeof node` bytes (in reality it may be even a little more) and then you have full memory access to the block pointed to by `n`.

In general you should call `malloc` in this way:

```
node *n;
n = malloc(sizeof *n);
```

1. without a cast
2. with `sizeof *n` instead of `sizeof <datatype>`. If you change the datatype (for example you have a typo and instead of `typedef .... node` you've writen `typedef ... nhode`. Then you only have to change the declarations of the variables and the rest of the code doesn't have to be changed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code is also right just "temp" is pointing to a garbage value so you have to initialized that.

```
temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your right on the first part, it segfaults because node* temp isn't pointing anywhere (well, somewhere, but not to allocated memory).

I don't know why the second one "works". I suspect it only appears to work, in that it's not crashing. But since temp was never initialized, who know where it's sticking that '100'. Maybe just hanging around to crash later. Either way, writing to unitialized memory isn't a good idea ;-0